# Find best machine learning for predicting category of products

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, text-classification

I have a dataframe that contains product and in this dataframe I have some features like: brand, `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`, `city`, `desc`, `image_count`, `mileage`, `price`, `title`, `year`.
The goal is predicting category of products. I have 1 billion training data and important features for prediction are title and description that are text type.
I like to know what algorithm is best for my prediction? I'm a beginner in machine learning and confused among different algorithms. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question fits [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

But just to give a start-off, you should look onto concepts like:

- Decision Trees
- SVMs
- Linear regression

Also while creating a model please do keep in mind about:

- Overfitting
- Hyperparameters(Learning rate, epochs, dropout etc.)
- Performance Evaluation(Accuracy, Precision, Recall etc.)

Good video playlists for beginner level machine learning are available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4NlfvrRCdg&list=PLl-BBnDxtUt1hLXmIwu27P22bTi6VwMkN) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwwWVAgJBcM&list=PLOVs_uP0NWOc3QBJFHFcvH6tBKqC1Nhjr)

Comment: I agree with @satya! Just to complement, I'd recommend you the Scikit-learning lib and [this](https://www.amazon.com.br/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Learn-TensorFlow/dp/1491962291) book!